# VsCode pycodestyle install failure

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, pycodestyle

Ubuntu: 20.04.1 LTS

VsCode: 1.49

Within VsCode I have attempted to install pycodestyle from the IDE with an error "**There is no pip installer selected in the environment**"

viewing the first note on the page https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting

I used:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install pycodestyle
```

This did not work and I received the same error when trying to select pycodestyle in VsCode.

Potential solution suggested to me is to uninstall and reinstall without sudo, as local user. I admit I do not follow this suggestion or how VsCode is handling pip/pip3 or pycodestyle on a deep level. Especially when the note I pointed out mentions installing with elevated prompt (sudo, elevated permissions).

Any insight on how to solve this install and selected environment error? Connecting the dots on **Why/How** I am getting this error, and why a suggested solution (mine or yours) works would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check whether the python you installed is available in the cmd window. (We need to install python outside of VSCode.)

   [image]
2. We can install the module using "`pip install pycodestyle`":

   [image]
3. Run:

   [image]

Reference: [Getting Started with Python in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial).